# Not Locating user position with MapView Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

When the app runs it gave me this:

Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

I know it is beacuse we have to ask first the user to use his location and I did as they suggested:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message</string>

  or/and

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message</string>
```

int the Info.plist file

Here it is how it looks:

[image: MapKit View]

[image: Info.plist]
but it steel give me that message and don't locate the device either in the iOS simulator or the device (iPad).

Comment: Have you activated Map capability ? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW9)

Comment: yes I did but I querrently found the solution. I'll post my own answer so this question can be solve, thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

before the implementation of your class

And this :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

or :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

not the both.
For me i do that in the `viewDidLoad` method

And it will be okay ;p

Comment: Do not use IS_OS_8_OR_LATER. There are proper ways to check if an API exists.

Answer (score -1):

Do this Authorisation on iOS 8

```
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0 &&
        [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
        //[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways
        ) {
        // Will open an confirm dialog to get user's approval
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        //[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    } else {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately
    }
```

Comment: still give me that message

Comment: Go to project settings - Capabilities - Background Modes - select Location Update.Then try again.

Comment: Do not check the `systemVersion`. There are proper ways to check if an API exists.